# Unplugging and pluging in ethernet cable restores lost connection

Tags: router, internet, lan, gigabit-ethernet

Last week I had my fibre connection installed by Zzoomm in England.

They installed a ADTRAN SDX622v as ONT. Which has a 10Gbps Ethernet port and it goes to my TP-Link Deco M4 Mesh router (3 satellites).

The issue is a few times a day I lose Internet connection! When I check the LEDs on the ONT box all seem fine but the router has no Internet, the router and WiFi connection is fine its just  there is no Internet connection coming from the ONT, as if something happens and it drops the connection.

However the strange thing is when I unblug the 10Gbps ethernet cable and plug it back in everything start working again.
I was convinced the issue was a faulty ONT so I asked the ISP to replace it for me, they brought a new one today and installed it, but the same issue happened again.

I'm so confused now, why would something like this happen and why unplugging and pluging back in the ethernet cable fixes the issue?

What I have tried so far with no luck:

1. Tried different new ethernet cables, Cat6 and Cat8
2. Tried with different routers, Eco M4, Netgear Orbi, and even router provided by the ISP

The time this happens is very random and not sure if it is related to load on the network, once it happens at 2pm and another time 5am

Could it be that I am using ethernet backhaul for two of the satellites? I read somewhere that this has caused issues for some users.

Comment: Are you able to force port negotiation or can you put a gigabit switch between ont and router? Also, why do you have a 10gigabit connection but a router only capable od gigabit? Seems like a waste.

Comment: Not sure, if I can do that on Deco, but I have another router which I can do it there, yeah I am planning to run 10gbe on my internal network, my actual router and and switch hasn't arrived yet!

Comment: Negotiation is on Full-Duplex and 1Gbps which is correct!